# mod_rewrite infinite loop with SEO friendly URLs

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm tidying up my urls to make them SEO friendly, but I have run into the issue of getting into an infinite loop and although I have read various other articles, I can't seem to find an answer to my question.

Example:

- Current URL : www.example.co.uk/aboutus.php
- Required SEO friendly URL: www.example.co.uk/about-us

Note: Since the URLS are slightly different I can't just drop off the `.php`

I can get the /about-us link to correctly rewrite to show the `/about.php` content using:

```
RewriteRule ^about-us /aboutus.php [NC,L]
```

But, what I also need to achieve is that the old url which is indexed in Google is redirected to the new url to preserve page rank:

```
RewriteRule ^aboutus.php /about-us [NC,L,R=301]
```

But these two rules get stuck in a loop, how can I resolve this please?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

need to check an incoming request

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s\/aboutus\.php\s
RewriteRule . /about-us [NC,L,R=301]
```

Comment: I thought this had solved it, but some caching issues were masking the real result. This doesn't seem to work as intended, the page doesn't get redirected.  Any further thoughts?  Thanks